# How can I replace the nested loops with Stream API

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java-stream

Is it possible to replace the nested loop in the code below with Stream API?

```
Map<String, List<Role>> roleByUserUsername = roles.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(//some foo that return userName
                Role::getRoleId,
                Collectors.toList()));

List<User> users = List.of(new User(), new User());
HashMap<String, User> userByRoleId = new HashMap<>();

for (final User user : users) {
    for (final Role roles1 : roleByUserUsername.get(user.getPassword())) {
        userByRoleId.put(roles1.getRoleId(), user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten the list of roles obtained from the map `roleByUsername`.

*By the way, there is an inconsistency: according to its name the *map* is meant to contain *usernames* as *keys*, but in the loop you're accessing it by providing the result returned by the call `getPassword()`.*

Then you need to apply `collect` as a terminal operation and provide collector `toMap()` as an argument in order to generate a map which associates `roleId` with a single *user*.

```
List<Role> roles = // initialing the list of roles
    
Map<String, List<Role>> roleByUsername = roles.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Role::getRoleId));
    
List<User> users = List.of(new User(), new User());
        
Map<String, User> userByRoleId = users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> roleByUsername.get(user.getPassword()).stream()
                .map(role -> Map.entry(role.getRoleId(), user)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
```

But there's a logical problem here. Assuming that `roleId` is unique for every role, but there could multiple users having the same role. Unless you have designed an application where every *user* has a unique *role*.

Therefore, it makes sense to change the map type to `Map<String, List<User>>` so that a collection of *user* would be mapped to each `roleId`.

And to achieve that, we need to change the collector from `toMap` to `groupingBy()` in conjunction with `mapping()` and `toList()`.

```
Map<String, List<User>> userByRoleId = users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> roleByUsername.get(user.getPassword()).stream()
                .map(role -> Map.entry(role.getRoleId(), user)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

*Sidenotes:*

- Collector `groupingBy()` has a flavor that expects only one argument - `classifier` *function*. It will store all elements mapped to the same *key* into a list by default. You don't need to provide `toList()` as a downstream.
- Write your code against interfaces like `Map`, don't make it dependent on concrete implementations: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: It is just sample of imagine code, so there is no logic. Thank you very much, it is help to me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
users.stream().forEach(user->roleByUserUsername.get(user.getPassword()).forEach(role->userByRoleId.put(role.getRoleId(), user)));
```